# Pause MDB message Processing

Tags: jboss, queue, jms, message-driven-bean, hornetq

Can we pause the MDB message processing for some time? For example: Jboss 1-deployed MDB for message processing. Jboss 2:-Bean for gathering user details. If the MDB from jboss 1 calls bean in jboss 2 for getting users details. If this is the case, when we restart the Jboss 2, we need to pause the MDB in jboss 1 till the jboss 2 is UP. Is there any option to pause MDB, so that we can avoid failure of message?

Comment: In JBoss4,5 you could setup dependencies between JMX beans - BarrierController / Barrier and make the MDB dependent on the Barrier, so pausing could be done via starting and stopping the barrier. I have not been able to find a direct replacement of this functionality in JBoss 7 AS. I'm still looking - any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can stop an MDB without stopping the whole application. It is possible with Spring JMS, but not with regular message driven beans.

What you could do, and is apparently possible, is [pausing a queue](http://hornetq.sourceforge.net/docs/hornetq-2.1.2.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#d0e6140). HornetMQ does give you the possibility to switch the queue to "receive only mode", though I don't know if this is available via the admin console.

Comment: Yeah.. you can pause a queue.

Answer (score 2):

In JBoss (4.x and 5.x), you can look up the MDB through the JMX Console and pause delivery of messages.

1. Go to the jmx console (`http://yourserver:8080/jmx-console/` where 8080 is the HTTP port)
2. Click `jboss.j2ee` in the left-hand pane
3. In the right-hand pane, find and click on your MDB. Usually, it will look something like

   `jar=file-containing-your-MDB.jar,name=NameOfYourMDB,service=EJB3`
4. To pause, click the "Invoke" button next to "stopDelivery"
5. To resume, click the "Invoke" button next to "startDelivery"

Comment: Have you found some equivalent with JBoss 7?

Comment: @pjklauser Does JBoss 7 not have this in the JMX console? I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the Queue on HornetQ. (I'm not sure about JBoss Messaging, but I'm pretty sure you do)

Look for the message pause and resume on the JMX Console