# How do I pause / suspend a message-driven bean from consuming?

Tags: jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, jmx, message-driven-bean, apache-tomee

I know I could re-enqueue, but I'd like to know if I can enable/disable anything using the internals or JMX

I am using TomEE+ 1.6.0, which relies on ActiveMQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible using the JMX console of the Apache Tomcat.
Have a look here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html

A similar problem concerning the JBoss AS in conjunction with the HornetQ Framework which is also JMS based, is disussed here.
[Pause MDB message Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385244/pause-mdb-message-processing)